# Delete rows with checkedbox in DatagridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid and added checkedboxs to delete some rows when I want. But the code I've used is not 100% right because when I check 1 or 2 rows and then click the delete button I've created it deletes all my rows and not only the ones i've selected.. What is wrong ?

```
BindingSource myDataListBindingSource;
myDataListBindingSource = new BindingSource();

dataGrid_reservations.DataSource = myDataListBindingSource;     
gestion_hotel bdd1 = new gestion_hotel();
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid_reservations.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    row = dataGrid_reservations.Rows[i];
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[1].Value);
        dataGrid_reservations.Rows.Remove(row);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: My first thought is that `Value` isn't what you think it is.  Obviously, it's always equating to `True`.  Have you stepped the loop to inspect the value each time?

Comment: You should remove from your binding source and then refresh the grid rather than manipulating the grid itself. But if you really want to loop over the rows, do it backwards, from count to zero instead of doing `i--`

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes and it seems it is not even doing the "for" loop ...

Answer (score 0):

this is how you check if a checkbox is checked

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[1];
        if (chk.Value  == chk.TrueValue)
        {
            //it is checked
        }
        else
        {
            //it isnt checked
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have a problem with the '.Controls[0]', it says there is no "Controls" method using DatagridViewcell as argument.

Comment: Yes, it is working now ! It seems my problem is to link checked rows with the "delete command" because using 
`dataGrid_reservations.Rows.Remove(row);`
in the case "if checked true" delete all my rows and not only the one I've selected.